How do I ensure that celery workers have access to the same .env file as flask?
I'm working on a flask server and trying to integrate celery to handle transformation of data that comes in via a webhook. I use environment variables extensively in my flask setup for things like API keys and database access, and I have all of these stored in a .env file. I would like to be able to have an instance of flask in the celery worker to provide access to sqlalchemy models, the db object, etc., but when I try to create a worker, the application factory for Flask fails because the .env variables are nowhere to be found. Is there some way I should be pre-loading them into Flask before attempting the db init?
Running the command
celery -A make_celery worker --loglevel INFO

results in
RuntimeError: Either 'SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI' or 'SQLALCHEMY_BINDS' must be set.

Flask is able to run just fine on its own and I'm having a hard debugging the worker because it's not printing to the console.
My make_celery file is this:
import os

from app import create_app

flask_app = create_app(os.getenv('FLASK_CONFIG') or 'default')
celery_app = flask_app.extensions["celery"]

and the create_app method (kind of anonymized) is this:
from celery_app import celery_init_app
from config import config

db = SQLAlchemy()


def create_app(config_name):
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object(config[config_name])
    config[config_name].init_app(app)

    # worker fails here every time as SQLAlCHEMY_DATABASE_URI is not set
    db.init_app(app)

    with app.app_context():
        #not included is importing of models and migrate init

        app.config.from_mapping(
            CELERY=dict(
                broker_url="amqp://guest:guest@127.0.0.1:5672//",
                result_backend=app.config['CELERY_BACKEND_URL'],
                task_ignore_result=True,
            ),
        )
        app.config.from_prefixed_env()
        celery_init_app(app)

    return app

And the celery_init_app() method that is included in the create_app() method:
def celery_init_app(app: Flask) -> Celery:
    class FlaskTask(Task):
        def __call__(self, *args: object, **kwargs: object) -> object:
            with app.app_context():
                return self.run(*args, **kwargs)

    celery_app = Celery(app.name, task_cls=FlaskTask)
    celery_app.config_from_object(app.config["CELERY"])
    celery_app.set_default()
    app.extensions["celery"] = celery_app
    return celery_app

I'm new to Flask and Celery both and can't crack this one.
I ran the above celery worker command, expecting it to create a worker that would have access to an instance of the flask app and all of its components, but instead it failed to initiate the sqlalchemy db object because of missing environment variables.

EDIT: The worker create command and the response didn't load correctly, so here they are:
celery -A make_celery worker --loglevel INFO
RuntimeError: Either 'SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI' or 'SQLALCHEMY_BINDS' must be set.

I've also tried a solution suggested by Miguel Grinberg to load_dotenv within the worker creation (make_celery) and it still has the same issue.

Got a response back from Miguel Grinberg right after posting this and it fixed it. Just had to load_dotenv in the make_celery method. Hopefully this helps someone else!
Deleted this answer after posting it because it didn't work and then it did. I had to update the make_celery class to load the absolute path of the .env before even importing the create_app method.

make_celery.py
import os
from flask.cli import load_dotenv

from app import create_app

load_dotenv()  # add this !

flask_app = create_app(os.getenv('FLASK_CONFIG') or 'default')
celery_app = flask_app.extensions["celery"]

